# Redis - monitoring maximum memory before inserts fail?

Tags: memory, redis

While [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450932/redis-monitoring-memory-usage) does not address the actual issue of: How to detect with client (eg redis-py) that redis is running out of memory constraint not by machine but by the maxmem configuration? Before inserts fail which command to use in the programm to detect about to be full?

My first guess is: [info](https://redis.io/commands/info) and check if `used_memory_peak` < `maxmem` setting. Is this correct?

(Besides, for out of machine memory, since defrag, use which setting, none of the returned `INFO` fields help here)

Well should i just try an insert and see if fail (but that would be after the fact then.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trail and error, good enough tested by running
 `while true; do redis-cli lpush mm longstringhere; done;` results on `maxmem - used_memory` < 0.1MB with insert failures:

> (error) OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'.

So i have set i poll it via redis-py client and once the diff goes <1mb threshold throw up, sry raise Error of course. Make sure the `user_memory` memory addon of your longest command is < threshold too of course otherwise you run into it on insert.
I try to figure how to calc the ~percentage of used mem so i get notification way earlier eg 90% of maxmem, therefore this solution is fine.

Info dump:

```
# Memory
used_memory:3126272
used_memory_human:2.98M
used_memory_rss:5292032
used_memory_rss_human:5.05M
used_memory_peak:4914296
used_memory_peak_human:4.69M
used_memory_peak_perc:63.62%
used_memory_overhead:696654...
```

Furthermore maxmem is not a hardcap, when running it further by eg adding members to existing set.

```
used_memory:3162584
used_memory_human:3.02M
```

code to get percent 0-100

```
rmem_info = pipe.info(section='memory')
{'redis_mem_percent': math.ceil(rmem_info['used_memory'] / rmem_info['maxmemory'] *100)}
```